# Access properties while declaring object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to access a value from the current value's parent but without success. I have these 2 sample javascript codes to demonstrate my issue:

---

**1)**

```
var x = {
    y : {
        a : "a",
        ab : this.a + "b"
    }
};
```

console.log(x.y);

```
> Object {
    a : a,
    ab : undefinedb
}
```

---

**2)**

```
var x = {
    y : {
        a : "a",
        ab : x.y.a + "b"
    }
};

console.log(x.y); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined
```

Comment: You cannot reference the object from inside the declaring object literal (conceptually, it *doesn't exist yet*). It must be done in two steps, or by using a function and deferred evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.y` and `this` are undefined as at that point they are `undefined`. What I mean is that when you create an anonymous object it does not really exist until the closing `}`.

So another way to achieve what you want would be:

```
var x = {
     y : {a : "a"}
}

x.y.ab = x.y.a + "b"
```

This way the `ab` variable is being set after `x` and `y` have both been initialised, and therefore `x.y.a` is now set.

If you really want to set x.y.ab during initialisation then you would need to do it more formally with functions and closures. Something like the following.

```
var x = function(){
  this.a = 'foo';
  this.b = this.a + ' bar';
}() // Immediate function call so I don't have to create it.

console.log(x.b); // logs 'foo bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

When using literals, you can't until the statement that defines those variables is executed.

One good way is:

```
var x = {};

x.a = 'hey';

x.b = x.a + ' how you doing?';

alert(x.b);
```

Or more compactly:

```
var x = {
    a: 'hey'
};

x.b = x.a + ' how you doing?';

alert(x.b);
```