# Reference own properties on initialization

Tags: javascript

Can one reference own properties on initialization of object?

I have an object that should be unique and only exist as one so I 
have no initializer etc.

Using something like this:

```
var Myobj = {
    property1 : aaa,
    property2 : bbb,
    property3 : {a: self.property1 }
                /*  ^-- is this somehow possible without using a function? 
                        Or a better way to solve / structure this. .init() 
                        best option? */
};
```

**>> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF77D/) <<**

The *real* object, (in the real code), has an add function that takes options on
what function to use etc. It is sort of a wrapper for *"addEventListener"* where
the point is to be able to remove listener - which require non anonymous function
reference.

Function to use within *Myobj* is specified by string, or numeric key in options to
`Myobj.add()`.

Comment: No, this won't work without *procedural code*. You can't reference other parts of an object that isn't completely initialized and assigned to a variable yet from within itself.

Comment: Sorry for the duplication here. My search phrases somehow missed this.

Comment: Don't worry about it-- it's a bit of a hard duplicate to find, since there are lots of other questions with "object", "property", "reference", and "initialization" in them. I *knew* that a duplicate existed (because I've seen come up before) and it still took me a while to find it.

Comment: Does my answer not work?

Comment: Thanks @deceze, you gave some insight in your comments here. I'll go for *procedural code* in a init() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object literals` remain `undefined` until the closing `}`, so you'd either have to make property3 a function or make the whole object a function.

```
var Myobj = {
    property1 : 'aaa',
    property3 : function (){ return { a : this.property1 } }
};
```

or

```
var MyObj = function(){
  this.property1 = 'aaa',
  this.property3 = { a: this.property1 }
}
var MyObjInstance = new MyObj();
```

This has been asked a lot of times: [Access properties while declaring object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304446/access-properties-while-declaring-object/15304531#15304531)

Comment: Thanks. Believe I see it a bit clearer now. Only have to decide upon a design to use.

Comment: Your `var a` is not the same thing as `Myobj.property3.a`. The two have very different visibility/scope.

Comment: My mistake, updated to reflect property3.a

Comment: You still have to access it like `Myobj.property3().a`, which is not the same as `Myobj.property3.a`.

Comment: Yes but its a compromise

Comment: So something like this then perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/XF77D/1/ , looking at it I guess I end up using a initialization function after all :P. Somehow suspect that would be faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use a placeholder array:

```
var prop = new Array();
var Myobj = {
    property1 : 'aaa',
    property2 : 'bbb',
    property3 : {a: prop}
};
prop.push(Myobj.property1);

window.alert(Myobj.property3.a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y2XwC/1/

Comment: Thanks. Interesting approach. I do not believe I'm going to use it in this case, but I'll remember it down the line as a design option if it should be appropriate.

Comment: This makes `Myobj.property3.a[0] == 'aaa'`. Not the same as `Myobj.property3.a == 'aaa'`.

Comment: @deceze It works without needing the index.

Comment: Depends how you define "works". It *is* an array, so things like `Myobj.property3.a.substr(1)` won't work.

Comment: The advantage would be that arrays are mutable, so he could change the value later: http://jsfiddle.net/y2XwC/3/

Comment: Maybe the answer here is that if the two values need to stay in sync, they should not be separate values to begin with. But if they're just initialized to the same value but can diverge later, arrays are of no advantage.

Comment: He asked how he could do it without a function. This is my attempt. Sorry if it's completely useless.